# Concurrently updating entity depending entity attribute

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have created an entity User and it has integer attribute transaction quota. I need to update transaction quota depending on its value.

If it is greater than 0, then it needs to be decremented, else its value needs to retained.

So here is my algorithm.

1. Retrive user entity from database.
2. Check transaction quota, if transaction quota greater than 0, reduce it by one.
3. Persist the changed user entity.

In above case, when concurrent request comes if two thread retrieves same user entity and 
then both threads read same transaction quota value and if it is greater than 0 then both reduces by 1 and updates the user entity.

ex.

```
ThreadA: val = e.getTxnQuota(); val = 5
ThreadB: val = e.getTxnQuota(); val = 5
ThreadA: e.setTxnQuota(val- 1); val = 4 
ThreadB: e.setTxnQuota(val- 1); val =4
ThreadA: eDao.save(e);
ThreadB: eDao.save(e);
```

In above case value saved is 4 and not 3.

So is there any way in which I can create an atomic transaction in which I can check transaction quota and update the User entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *locking*, and it's usually preferrable to use *optimistic* locking. JPA comes with a standard mechanism to do that. Just add a version field to your entity, and annotate it with @Version:

```
@Version
private long version;
```

Et voilà!

Each time a User is saved, its current version will be compared to the one in database, and incremented:

```
update user set ..., version = version + 1 where id = ... and version = theVersionOfTheUserWhenItWasLoaded
```

(this all happens transparently).

If the versions don't match, then nothing is updated, the JPA engine detects it, throws an OptimisticLockException, and marks the transaction for rollback.

Side note: in your scenario above, the call to `save()` is unnecessary: all changes made to an attached entity are automatically saved in the database. No need to save the entity.

Comment: Thanks JB.. I put optimistic locking and retrying transaction on OptimisticLockExcetion. It is working very well.